# Rails :redirect to different controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I need to refresh my HTML view as soon as I receive some data from my android application. I get items list from my android app. As soon as the items are stored in my DB, I need to refresh the summary view with received items list. My problem is I am unable to do this process automatically. Like my view is displaying contents perfectly if I enter the url. But every time when I receive items list, I need to manually refresh to fetch updated item list from DB. I used `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5" />` to refresh page and this too works fine, but instead I need to refresh only when new items are received and stored in DB. Below is the controller code from my lists controller where I save received items

```
def create
    lists = params[:list].collect{|list_attributes| List.new(list_attributes)}
    valid,not_valid = lists.partition{|list| list.valid?}

    if not_valid.blank?
      lists.map(&:save)
      @lists = lists
      format.html { redirect_to @list, notice: 'List was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render json: @list, status: :created, location: @list }
    else
      format.html { render action: "new" }
      format.json { render json: @list.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end

  end
```

I have to refresh view once items are saved in DB i.e. after `@lists = lists` in above code. I read a lot many tutorials and understand that i should not be using render as I have to call a different controller and not call a method of this controller. I tried using redirect_to like below;

```
      @lists = lists
      @summary = summary_controller.new
      redirect_to @summary
```

summary is the controller which displays view(and i am trying to call from lists controller) but its giving error. I tried more options too but its unable to identify summary controller name.

I am new to rails and tried many things suggested in similar posts but none of them working. Seems like I am missing something or unable to understand the concept of calling different controller. Please advise. Thanks.

Comment: where do you want to redirect ? look there is not `@list` variables in your method if you want to redirect `summary` then just do `redirect_to new_summary_path(:lists => @lists)` and in summary controller `def new` method you got the lists array through `params[:lists]`

Comment: @RajarshiDas: kindly ignore my previous comment(i didn't see the whole comment). Thanks for pointing this but I need not pass anything from here to that controller. It has the code to fetch from lists and do further processing. Moreover I had defined only index method in controller which corresponds to index.html.erb view file. Do i still need to have 'new' in summary controller. Please advise.